# Reset JSF Backing Bean(View or Session Scope)

Tags: jsf

I want to reset by JSF backing bean when some method is invoked. Assume that there is a command button, someone press it and after succesfull transaction, my View or Session scope JSF bean should be reseted. Is there a way to do that?

Thank

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution for View scope.

```
    public static void removeViewScopedBean(String beanName) 
    {
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove(beanName);
    }
```

Comment: This is just plain clumsy and should not have been necessary for view scoped beans.

Comment: @BalusC it should not be necessary, but I want my Bean destroyed when the user leaves the page (via closing Tab or typing custom URL). And the View Beans are not destroyed until the session is invalidated. So the View is gone, but the Bean still there - so this seems to be the only way. And the Session can not be invalidated as long as other tabs are still active...

Answer (score 13):

A view scoped bean will be recreated when you return non-`null` or non-`void` from the action method, even if it would go back to the same view. So, just return a `String` from the action method, even if it's just an empty string:

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "";
}
```

To make it complete, you could consider sending a redirect by appending the `?faces-redirect=true` query string to the returned outcome.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "viewId?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

A session scoped bean is in first place the wrong scope for whatever you're currently trying to achieve. The bean in question should have been be a view scoped one. Ignoring that, you could just recreate the model in the action method, or very maybe invalidate the session altogether (which would only also destroy all other view and session scoped beans, not sure if that is what you're after though).

Comment: what if the backingbean is session scoped and I still want to achieve the above result ?

Answer (score 3):

just clear all views:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().clear();`

and remember to implements Serializable in all views

Comment: I like this better - so you don't have to care about individual beans getting left behind... clean slate - clear everything.

Comment: Using myfaces (2.2.27) the clear() has no effect while if I remove the single bean it works

Answer (score 3):

You could also refresh the page from javascript, so the ViewScoped Bean will be reseted, for example in a primefaces commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton value="Button" action="#{bean.someAction()}" oncomplete="location.reload()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem with code like this:

```
((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession().removeAttribute("bean name");
```

By this way I enter to session scoped bean and reset it without the data that was there before