# Reset JSF Backing Bean of Viewscope

Tags: jsf-2

I have one managed bean in viewscope i want to reset form which is using this scope. According to Baluc from this post [Reset JSF Backing Bean(View or Session Scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458911/reset-jsf-backing-beanview-or-session-scope)
I did the same in my code :

```
    public String reset(){
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("myBean");
        return "SamePage?faces-redirect=true"; 

    }
```

But it is not working.
Can some tell any solution .

Comment: Please describe the error. "Not working" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
public void reset(){

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("myBean");

}
```

or this

```
public String reset(){

     return "SamePage"; 

}
```

Comment: Good! First option helped me ! +1

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that, by returning something non-null and non-void, you don't need that call to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("myBean")`. The following should work (eventually):

```
public String reset() {
    return "";
}
```

I say "eventually" because I don't remember if the view-scoped beans are destroyed before or after the render response phase. I suspect that's why BalusC suggested adding `?faces-redirect=true` to the return value.