# View keeps older value when I clear my backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

Is JSF value binding unidirectional or bidirectional?

When I clear my backing bean data, view still keeps the older values.
Is this the way JSF works?
I want to know a way to sync view with backing bean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, databinding is bidirectional. But this means little, without answering the two key questions:

- WHEN reading and writing happens,
- ON WHAT CONDITION it happens.

And the answers are:

- Data is pushed from controls into bean after postback, if EVERY component is valid.
- Data is read from beans just before rendering, that is after each action happened and each standard event fired (command buttons, valuechange events etc.).

This means that contrary to first intuitions:
 - components like inputs do keep their state and it is detached from backing beans. It can be kept for a long time, even many postbacks, without any synchronization with the backing bean (for example in case when any other component on your form fails to validate).

The simplest way to imagine the lifecycle is:

1. components restore their state using request data and possibly some other, configuration-dependent means [postback only]
2. if conversion and validation are fine, then the data from components is copied over to backing beans using bindings if not, the next step is skipped, but components still get remember their state  [postback only]
3. action are executed (view action, commands). At this stage you can always read data from beans and be sure it's valid (not "coherent", more like "each component in isolation has an acceptable value"). You can also change values in beans being sure they will be used in the next step.
4. bindings are used by components to pull data from backing beans and pull it.

The takeaways are:

- if you try to put any logic in getters and setters, you have a problem. If any of your setters sets some additional property, you end up with code that will set some other value, the results may depend on the order of invocation of bindings (step 2);
- the only good moment to change any data is step 3: the moment where actions are executed;
- if you don't have any action, you can also use PreRenderView event, it gets called between steps 3 and 4 (and can be used to move some data into beans if you have a pure GET page, without postbacks).
- changing beans or relying on values from beans in converters, validators and valuechangelisteners - is tricky at least.

If you try to use JSF going along with the grain, it's a real pleasure to use. If try to go against the grain and bend JSF to your ideas of how a web framework should work (like using business validation in your validators, changing model inside a converter, reading database from constructor etc.) you will need a lot of BalusC's help :-)

Comment: Note that binding will be bidirectional **only** if the attributes are in the submitted form, otherwise JSF will only use getters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: and don't forget that the server *needs* to be be plugged in! electricity is crucial for JavaServer Faces to work.

Comment: Electricity is crucial even for you to charge your electronic device, log in into SO and add such comments!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure exactly what you're asking, but yes, if your beans are other than request scope, they will populate your html form controls with the previous values.

if your beans are view scope or session scope, you can still control the rendered values by manipulating the model values in your bean's action menthods (commandLink/commanButton actions)

if you want the values to be cleared on a later visit to the same page, you should make your page beans request scope.

You can if you wish, micromanage the UIComponents directly for complete control by using bindings rather than value, allowing you to create and manage the UIComponents directly in your bean.e.g.

`<h:inputText binding="#{bean.inputComponent" />` and in your code

```
public class myBean {
    private UIInput inputComponent;

    public UIComponent getInputComponent() {
        // create your UIComponent here, and manage values in your command methods
    }

    public void setInputComponent(UIComponent component) {
         inputComponent = component;
    }
```

}

Comment: That's not quite correct. The request scoped bean will be recreated, and repopulated (with client values) upon next request, though view scoped bean wouldn't be recreated, but restored from the view (chicken eggs excluded). But the data will be kept intact.

Comment: ahh yes, I see your point, I editied my answer to be clearer - but  you can if you wish also completely reset the view by returning the same viewid  in your action methods - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458911/reset-jsf-backing-beanview-or-session-scope for example

Comment: For sure, because it won't be a postback. But I understood OP's question that he would like changes he produced in one of the (listener) methods to *be reflected* in his view. By the way, did you know what the binding attribute of UI components does in respect to view scoped beans?

Answer (score 0):

JSF does what you tell it to do.

In order to refresh the view (after you make some changes to your bean) you need either to do a *postback to the original view*, by returning null/void from you action method, or specify client ids (or other accepted values like @form) of components to be executed (updated) and later rendered (refreshed) as *attributes of `<f:ajax>` tag* attached to your component that is supposed to make changes to your bean.